# robot framework: telnet execute command "Prompt is not set"

Tags: robotframework

Trying to run this piece of code, but a "Prompt is not set" error keeps occurring at the Execute Command line.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Telnet
Library    Telnet  ${out}
Library    Collections
Library    Collections  ${y}
Library    Collections  ${x}

*** Variables ***
${ip}    0.0.0.0
${port}    0

*** Test Cases ***
telnet to server
    Open Connection    ${ip}  ${port}

verify something
    ${out}=  Execute Command  ls
    ${y}=  Get From List  ${out}  0
    Should Match Regexp  ${y}  /^ID$/

Exit Test
    Close All Connections
```

I have also tried deleting "Library    Telnet  ${out}" and replacing the " ${out}=
  Execute Command  ls" line with the following, but receive the same error.

```
Write  ls
Set Prompt  ${out}
${out}=  Read Until Prompt
```

Is there a problem with the syntax? Or, is the usage of the "prompt" completely wrong? (if so, how can i fix this?)

(note: this is a first attempt at robot framework, so please feel free to comment on any other problems!)

Comment: please show the actual error.

Comment: what do you mean by actual error? the only error i've found in the log file is "Prompt is not set."

Comment: So, you're getting a blank screen with exactly these words "Prompt is not set"? There's no other information -- no other context at all?

Comment: yep, there's nothing else printed and no other context. i've already checked the small stuff like spacing and went through different ways to do the same thing. do you know of any other way to write a command and store the output?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is in the Telnet docs. I use RED Robot Editor which can show me docs for Telnet and Telnet KW by hover over Telnet entry in editor, this can also be generated via command line:

```
python -m robot.libdoc Telnet show
```

There is a part about Prompt:

```
== Prompt ==

Often the easiest way to read the output of a command is reading all
the output until the next prompt with `Read Until Prompt`. It also makes
it easier, and faster, to verify did `Login` succeed.

Prompt can be specified either as a normal string or a regular expression.
The latter is especially useful if the prompt changes as a result of
the executed commands. Prompt can be set to be a regular expression
by giving ``prompt_is_regexp`` argument a true value (see `Boolean
arguments`).

Examples:
| `Open Connection` | lolcathost | prompt=$              |
| `Set Prompt`      | (> |# )    | prompt_is_regexp=true |
```

Check Telnet docs for more help and examples.

ps. I don't see reason to import Telnet with parameter:

```
Library    Telnet  ${out}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I am too late to answer, I did not see the exact expected answer hence answering this now.
You need to set 2 things in Open Connection.

1. `prompt_is_regexp=yes`
2. `prompt=#{Your expected prompt}`